# 403 Forbidden Apache server Raspberry Pi

Tags: apache

so I've got a nice little (apache) server running now on a Raspberry Pi. But when I access it through FTP and upload some new code to it I need to apply the following command to get the files to show up on the site every time:

```
sudo chmod 0755 -R /var/www
```

If I do not do this I get the error "403 forbidden" when I try to go to it.

So what I'm looking for is a way to keep the permissions set every time I upload something to this folder (/var/www). I'm sorry if this question has been asked many times but I can't seem to find the correct phrase to google this..

Comment: Try chmod 1755 on the directory. Without the -r that sets a sticky bit

Comment: Nope, it still needs the chmod 0755 -R to appear :(

Comment: or are you just using filezilla over ssh ?

Comment: I'm using vsftpd on my Pi

Comment: Was this problem ever solved? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Obiously, this is a file permissions error. If you are using a website designer software (such as Adobe Dreamweaver) you should check to see the settings of file save and FTP upload to check they are written to the server with the correct permissions.

I assume this error occurs whenever you overwrite the file, if i'm wrong, please correct me. Which makes me think that it's to do with the permissions that the file is saved as.

A possible solution would be to change the file permissions of the file on the local machine (not the webserver) to 755 and then upload to the webserver. Hopefully the permissions should be retained.

*Note: you can change permissions in an ftp client such as filezila*